# std::type_info::before and collation order

Tags: c++11, std, typeinfo

[std::type_info::before](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/before)

Above reference mentions about

> the implementation's collation order

What is implied by this with respect to specific types? How does this notion impact user defined types?

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is a total order of all types, that is required to remain consistent only for a single invocation of a program.

Comment: It is ok for `name()` to return `""` for all types; I don't think `typeid(char).before(typeid(int) && typeid(int).before(typeid(char))` is permitted; In short, `before` makes no mention of the return value of `name()`.

Comment: what is the concept of collation order?